# What Commitizen type should I use for a change that is an improvemant for an existing feature?

Tags: devops, git-commit, commitizen

Here are the Commitizen types:

[image]

What Commitizen type should I use for **a change that is an improvement for an existing feature**?

CZ resources :

- http://commitizen.github.io/cz-cli/
- https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed [on Github](https://github.com/commitizen/conventional-commit-types/issues/9#issuecomment-366867817). To quote one of the contributors:

> In my interpretation, `feat` could include updates to an existing feature (new features for that feature). We could consider changing its description, if that would help.

From the available options `feat` makes the most sense to me too.